# react-google-maps street view on mobile

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I implemented react-google-maps package in my application. Everything works fine but when I look website on mobile and go to street view there is some option turned on by default which enables that map turns around as mobile turns around. This option is turned on by default. There is a little mobile icon in the right corner and If I press it, this will be turned off and the only way to move in street view will be with fingers.
How do I make this "normal" movement with fingers a default when someone enters street view?

EDIT:
Add example

```
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow, } from 'react-google-maps'
import Image from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Image/Image'

class MapInfoComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    openInfoWindow: true,
  }

  onMarkerClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      openInfoWindow: !prevState.openInfoWindow,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} center={{ lat: 16.4555, lng: 14.1257, }}>
        <Marker position={{ lat: 16.4555, lng: 14.1257, }} onClick={this.onMarkerClick}>
          {this.state.openInfoWindow && (
            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onMarkerClick}>
              <Image src={logo} size="small" />
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </Marker>
      </GoogleMap>
    )
  }
}


const GoogleMapComponent = withGoogleMap(MapInfoComponent)
const MapComponent = withScriptjs(GoogleMapComponent)

const Maps = () => (
  <div styleName="container">
    <MapComponent
      googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS ||
        'addGoogleMapsKey'}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%', }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%', }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%', }} />}
    />
  </div>
)

export default Maps
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is called `motionTracking`.

With `react-google-maps`, I assume you're using the `StreetViewPanorama` component in your code. There's two props on it: `defaultMotionTracking` and `motionTracking`. Set `defaultMotionTracking` to false.

Otherwise the default ends up:

> Whether motion tracking is on or off. **Enabled by default when the motion tracking control is present**, so that the POV (point of view) follows the orientation of the device. This is primarily applicable to mobile devices. If motionTracking is set to false while motionTrackingControl is enabled, the motion tracking control appears but tracking is off. The user can tap the motion tracking control to toggle this option.

See [react-google-maps docs](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#streetviewpanorama) & [Google Maps Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/street-view#StreetViewPanoramaOptions.motionTracking).

EDIT: Per your example, here's a possible solution (haven't tested, but conceptually should work):

```js
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow, } from 'react-google-maps'
import Image from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Image/Image'

class MapInfoComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    openInfoWindow: true,
  }

  onMarkerClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      openInfoWindow: !prevState.openInfoWindow,
    }))
  }

  buildGoogleMap() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} center={{ lat: 16.4555, lng: 14.1257, }}>
        <Marker position={{ lat: 16.4555, lng: 14.1257, }} onClick={this.onMarkerClick}>
          {this.state.openInfoWindow && (
            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onMarkerClick}>
              <Image src={logo} size="small" />
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </Marker>
      </GoogleMap>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const googleMap = this.buildGoogleMap();
    googleMap.getStreetView().setMotionTracking(false);
    return googleMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tadas. I just checked it and added example in my post. I am not using StreetViewPanorama but the problem seems like the one that you described.

Comment: Try taking a look at the `GoogleMap` [source code](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/components/GoogleMap.jsx). It appears that there's an undocumented `setStreetView` method where you could construct and set your own  `StreetViewPanorama`. The method is briefly mentioned but not elaborated upon in [the docs](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap).

Don't have time to dive into this for a little while but let me know if that gets you anywhere

Comment: @Igor-Vuk added an example which should help